# Legend Spacing in tmap

Tags: r, cartography, maps, tmap

My problem is that I am using tmap to create cartographic maps, and similar to ggplot I need legend spacing between the legend keys but I can not figure out how to implement the legend spacing in tmap.

```
tm_shape(city_coords) +
      tm_symbols(shape = 4, size = 0.3, col = "black") +
      tm_layout(title = paste0(period_name),
                frame = TRUE,
                inner.margins = 0.125,
                legend.text.size = 0.5,
                legend.title.size = 0.5,
                legend.position = c("left","top")) +
      tm_scale_bar(position = c("right", "bottom"), text.size = 0.5, 
                   lwd = 0.1, color.dark = "grey2", width = 0.15)
```

This is my map above and my legend should look something like this:

[image]